# Flow type map return based on function string argument fn('a'):A, fn('b'):B

Tags: javascript, types, ecmascript-6, flowtype, complextype

So we have 2 functions:

```
const car = ():Car => {return {type: `car`, wheels: 4}};
const house = ():House => {return {type: `house`, rooms: 3}};
```

So I have a map:

`const map = {car, house}`

Now I have a function that based on the string invokes the car or bike like this:

```
type myType = (type:string):any;
const get:myType  = (type) => {
  return map[type]();
};
```

Now I call the function:

`const myVar = get('car');`

Now I would like flow to understand that `myVar` is a `Car` type. Is it possible and if yes, how?

I would like to keep this information in a map instead of doing the following:

```
type carType = (type:'car'):Car;
type houseType = (type:'house'):House;
const get:carType|houseType = (type) => {
  return map[type]();
};
```

Would be something similar to https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-keys but for the values. Also this seems relevant: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-objmap

Comment: Typing in JS seems like a nightmare to me. Why not just embrace the dynamic nature?

Comment: Because I prefer with flow. Sorry but I want to know that is car, so it can correct for me in case my code tries to access wheels when should be a car. Also could potentially give autocomplete.